# Mui PaginationItem not synchronizing when used in multiple components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hello I am using Pagination and PaginationItem from MUI

```
    <Stack>
  <Pagination
    count={count}
    renderItem={(item) => (
      <PaginationItem
        className="pagination"
        components={{ previous: ArrowBackIcon, next: ArrowForwardIcon }}
        {...item}
      />
    )}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
</Stack>
```

The functionality is working when you click the page numbers and arrow back and arrow forward icons

The problem is when user clicks page on 2, the duplicate pagination component is not synched to the current page

for Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize multiple instances of the `Pagination` component, you should use the `page` parameter, set it with state and pass this state to all the components you want to synchronize. To do this, you have to define this shared state inside the closest parent. One way to do it:

```js
...
// 1 is the default page
const [statePage, setStatePage] = useState(1);

function handlePageChange(e: any, page: number): void {
     ...
     setStatePage(page);
     ...
  }
...

return(
<Pagination
          page={statePage}
          onChange={handlePageChange}
        />
<OtherComponent />
<Pagination
          page={statePage}
          onChange={handlePageChange}
        />
```

Official documentation/tutorial on sharing state between components:
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components